# Spin TQFT's in dimensions (1+1)

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I don't seem to be able to find anything written about Spin TQFT's in dimension (1+1). Does anyone know any references? Or is there some reason it is uninteresting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is covered in Moore and Segal ["D-branes and K-theory in 2D topological field theory"](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/Dbranes_Ktheory_Final.pdf). In particular on around page 16 there is a characterization analogous to "1+1 TQFTs = Commutative Frobenius algebras".